# RewriteRule not working with all words

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a really weird problem.
I'm using apache2 with vhosts on debian 7.

The .htaccess file of one vhost looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^support$ /support.php [L]
RewriteRule ^privacy$ /privacy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^terms$ /terms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^downloads$ /downloads.php [L]

RewriteRule ^thisworks$ /test.php [L]
```

mod_rewrite is activated, 'AllowOverride All' is set.

The last rewrite rule is working, the others are not.

If I change

```
RewriteRule ^downloads$ /downloads.php [L]
```

in:

```
RewriteRule ^files$ /downloads.php [L]
```

it is working. I can access with example.com/files the downloads.php

But I do not want to use other words.
Why is it not working with the words support, privacy, terms, downloads?
Whats wrong here?
It seems like these words are banned.

Many many thanks.

Comment: These words are not reserved. I feel something else is the culprit